# How can I transform a JSON array returned by jq into an object with a single attribute with that list's data?

Tags: json, command-line, jq

Suppose that the output of a jq command is a list of objects. What would be the command to get this list as the attribute of an object? That is: transforming the output from a list into an object.

Example JSON list:

```json
[
  {"name":"Foo"},
  {"name":"Bar"}
]
```

Example desired output object:

*The attribute "items" has been added, and contains the list that serves as input.*

```json
{
  "items": [
    {"name":"Foo"},
    {"name":"Bar"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take the json document and put it as a "items" attribute of a dictionary.

```
jq '{items: .}'
```

Here is a good guide for the basics.  https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json